# How to get the PID of a PPID by substitution (C using bash)?

Tags: c, bash, pid

I have to write 2 programs :
1) The first only have to print its own PID - and it's OK

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int pid1;
    pid1 = getpid();
    printf("PID is : %d\n", pid1);
    return 0;
}
```

2) The second program have to print the PID and launch the first program's process by substitution

How can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch the first program's processus by substitution"? What does `bash` have to do with programming in C?

Comment: I don't really know what the teacher means but i think that it's about launching the program, calling the PID (of the child)... And i guess it's "shell" and not "bash"

Comment: You want to run the parent process instead of the child process ? Or do you wish to run the "Swapper process" which has pid = 0 and runs when ever there are no active processes in the system ?

Comment: Yes, the title of the exercice is to "replace a processus by another", so i guess that it's about running the parent process instead of the child's one !

Comment: You use the `system()` function to run a shell command from C. Or if you need to capture the output of the program, use `popen()`.

Comment: There's no such word as "processus", so what kind of title is that?

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to use the `execv()` function? That replaces the current process with another program.

Comment: Aha i m french, it's just "process", sorry !

Comment: Was there a lesson before the assignment that taught the language feature that you're supposed to be exercising?

Comment: Not really, that's why i m here ! But i m gonna try with execv() !

Comment: I haven't taken a programming class in many years, but in my day they didn't assign homework that required you to know things that weren't explained in the textbook or lecture before the assignment. I don't understand why we get so many questions like that here, unless it's because you don't go to the lectures.

Comment: I went to every lectures, really... We just don't have the same system ! But i guess i m gonna handle it thanks to execv() ! Thanks !

Comment: @J.Doe, If you actually don't know exactly what the teacher means, the best thing you can do is to ask him for an explanation.  We can be debating for eons here about what the teacher tried to explain.